# ¿Por qué los productos que agrego por búsqueda dentro del input select2 no se guardan correctamente?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Actualmente estoy realizando una consulta a la api de wordpress para traer productos, sin embargo tengo el siguiente problema; Como son más de 1000 productos estoy cargando inicialmente 100 productos y cuando el usuario baja se cargan progresivamente los demás productos. Sin embargo, cuando el usuario realiza una búsqueda en el input del select2, solo se guarda el ID y yo necesito el nombre, el peso y la cantidad. Ojo ya esto lo está haciendo bien con los productos que se cargan inicialmente pero no con los que se cargan cuando se buscan. Por ejemplo; Se cargan 10 productos si yo selecciono un producto de esos 10 se guardan perfectamente como deberían, sin embargo cuando busco un producto especifico, lo selecciono le agrego su cantidad el sistema solo me guarda el ID.

CODIGO:

```
    <div class="mb-3">
<label for="productos" class="form-label">Productos: <span id="product-count"></span></label>
  <select name="productos[]" id="productos" class="form-select" multiple required>
  <?php


  function get_all_products($page = 1) {
    global $consumer_key, $consumer_secret;
    $url = "https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=" . $consumer_key . "&consumer_secret=" . $consumer_secret . "&per_page=100&page=" . $page;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($output);
  }

  $products = [];
  $max_pages = 50;
  $page = 1;
  do {
    $current_products = get_all_products($page);
    $products = array_merge($products, $current_products);
    $page++;
  } while (count($current_products) > 0 && $page <= $max_pages);

  $initial_data = [];
  foreach ($products as $product) {
    $id = $product->id;
    $name = $product->name;
    $weight = $product->weight;
    echo "<option value='$id'>$id - $name (Peso: $weight kg)</option>"; // Cambie aquí
    $initial_data[] = ['id' => $id, 'text' => "$id - $name (Peso: $weight kg)", 'data' => ['name' => $name, 'weight' => $weight]]; // Cambie aquí
  }
  
  ?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

   

$('#productos').on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  $('option[value="' + data.id + '"]', this).remove();
  $(this).trigger('change');
});
    var productCount = <?php echo count($products); ?>;
    $('#product-count').text(productCount);

    $('#productos').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 0,
      initSelection: function (element, callback) {
  const initialData = <?php echo json_encode($initial_data); ?>;
  callback(initialData);

  // Agregar productos seleccionados manualmente
  initialData.forEach(producto => {
    $('#productos').val(producto.id).trigger('select2:select', {data: producto});
  });
},

      ajax: {
        url: 'https://web/wp-json/wc/v3/products',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
          var query = {
            consumer_key: '<?php echo $consumer_key; ?>',
            consumer_secret: '<?php echo $consumer_secret; ?>',
            search: params.term,
            per_page: 100,
            page: params.page || 1 // Añade el parámetro de página
          };
          return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
  params.page = params.page || 1;

  var results = [];
  $.each(data, function (index, item) {
    results.push({
      id: item.id,
      text: item.id + ' - ' + item.name + ' (Peso: ' + item.weight + ' kg)',
      data: {name: item.name, weight: item.weight} // Cambie aquí
    });
  });

  // Si la cantidad de productos devueltos es igual a per_page, entonces hay más productos para cargar
  var moreResults = data.length === 100;

  return {
    results: results,
    pagination: {
      more: moreResults
    }
  };
},
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.error('Error al cargar los productos:', textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>




</select>
<script>
  const allProducts = <?php echo json_encode($products); ?>;
</script>

</div>

<div id="productos-seleccionados">
  <!-- Aquí se van a agregar los productos seleccionados -->
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="maletas_productos_list.php">Cancelar</a>
<!-- Agregar SweetAlert2 CSS y JavaScript -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.20/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.20/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js'></script>

<!-- Agregar el botón "Crear maleta" -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="crearMaleta()">Crear maleta</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
  // Obtener elementos del DOM
  const contenedorProductosSeleccionados = document.getElementById("productos-seleccionados");

  // Agregar un event listener al select de productos
  $('#productos').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  const producto = e.params.data;
  const productoId = producto.id;

  // Verificar si el producto ya está en el contenedor
  if (document.getElementById(`producto-${productoId}`)) return;

  // Añadir el valor del producto seleccionado al <select>
  const selectedValues = $(this).val() || [];
  selectedValues.push(productoId);
  $(this).val(selectedValues).trigger('change');

   // Agregar un contenedor para el producto seleccionado
   const contenedorProducto = document.createElement("div");
  contenedorProducto.id = `producto-${productoId}`;

    // Agregar un span con el nombre del producto
  const spanNombreProducto = document.createElement("span");
  spanNombreProducto.innerHTML = producto.text;
  spanNombreProducto.setAttribute('data-nombre', producto.data.name); // Añade esta línea
  contenedorProducto.appendChild(spanNombreProducto);

   // Agregar un input de cantidad para el producto
   const inputCantidadProducto = document.createElement("input");
  inputCantidadProducto.type = "number";
  inputCantidadProducto.name = `cantidad-${productoId}`;
  inputCantidadProducto.value = 1;
  inputCantidadProducto.min = 1;
  inputCantidadProducto.classList.add("form-control", "my-2");
  inputCantidadProducto.setAttribute('data-peso', producto.data.weight); // Añade esta línea
  contenedorProducto.appendChild(inputCantidadProducto);

    // Agregar un botón para eliminar el producto
  const botonEliminarProducto = document.createElement("button");
  botonEliminarProducto.innerHTML = "Eliminar";
  botonEliminarProducto.type = "button";
  botonEliminarProducto.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "btn-sm", "ms-2");
  botonEliminarProducto.addEventListener("click", function() {
    contenedorProducto.remove();

     // Eliminar solo el producto correspondiente del Select2
    const selectedValues = $('#productos').val() || [];
    const index = selectedValues.indexOf(productoId.toString());
    if (index > -1) {
      selectedValues.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $('#productos').val(selectedValues).trigger('change');
  });
  contenedorProducto.appendChild(botonEliminarProducto);

    // Agregar el contenedor del producto al contenedor de productos seleccionados
    contenedorProductosSeleccionados.appendChild(contenedorProducto);
  });

  // Agregar un event listener al select de productos para manejar la eliminación directa de productos
  $('#productos').on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
    const productoId = e.params.data.id;

    // Eliminar el contenedor del producto correspondiente
    const contenedorProducto = document.getElementById(`producto-${productoId}`);
    if (contenedorProducto) {
      contenedorProducto.remove();
    }
  });
</script>





<br>


<!-- Agregar la función "crearMaleta" -->
<script>
function crearMaleta() {
  const formulario = document.getElementById("miFormulario");

  // Validar el formulario antes de enviarlo
  if (!formulario.checkValidity()) {
    formulario.reportValidity();
    return;
  }

  // Iterar sobre los productos seleccionados
  const selectedValues = $('#productos').val() || [];
  for (const productoId of selectedValues) {
    // Obtener el contenedor del producto y sus elementos
    const contenedorProducto = document.getElementById(`producto-${productoId}`);
    const spanNombreProducto = contenedorProducto.querySelector('span[data-nombre]');
    const inputCantidadProducto = contenedorProducto.querySelector('input[type="number"]');

    // Buscar el objeto de producto correcto en la lista de todos los productos
    const productoData = allProducts.find(p => p.id.toString() === productoId);

    // Crear y guardar los datos del producto en objetos
    const producto = {
  id: productoId,
  nombre: productoData.name,
  peso: productoData.weight || 0, // Asigna un valor predeterminado de 0 si el peso está vacío
  cantidad: inputCantidadProducto.value
};


    // Envía los datos del producto al servidor
    // Reemplaza esta línea con el código necesario para guardar los datos en la base de datos
    console.log(producto);
  }

  // Mostrar la alerta de éxito
  Swal.fire({
    title: '¡Éxito!',
    text: 'Maleta de pedidos creada correctamente.',
    icon: 'success',
    timer: 2000, // Ocultar automáticamente después de 2 segundos
    showConfirmButton: false
  }).then(() => {
    // Enviar el formulario después de que se oculte la alerta
    formulario.submit();
  });
}


</script>



</div>
```

PD: Las claves apis no son las correctas ni tampoco la URL, es para la demostración.